# Excel: How to calculate average difference between values in a row?

Tags: microsoft-excel, average

I have a row of numbers, say, `1 2 3` (each number is in separate column, of course). I want to calculate the average difference between all values. This means that I would calculate all the differences: `1-2=-1`, `1-3=-2` and  `2-3=-1`, and after that I take the average of the differences: `(-1-2-1)/3=-1,333...`. Is there a function that could do this? I would also calculate the largest and smallest (closest to 0) of these values as well as the median difference.

I tried to calculate the average as `=AVERAGE((C3:J3)-(B3:I3))`, when the values are in rows `B-J` but this does not give the same answer when I calculate the thing manually. Does anyone know how to do this? Doing this manually requires a massive amount of work that is not practical by any means.

**EDIT:**

There are 9 columns, I would like to calculate the difference between each possible combination of the values (but only in one direction) and then the average of those values.

Comment: The "average difference between all values" is unclear, could you expand a bit on that? Do you mean only the forward combinations (so a-b, a-c, a-d, b-c, b-d, c-d)? If you take every combination in both directions the average will always be zero. And is the number of items fixed? In that case, the formula is fairly simple [e.g. for four items, it is (3a+b-c-3d)/6]

Comment: You are only using two differences, don't you need to average all the differences ?  All you have to do is get your formula right.  It would help if you actually gave a sample of your real data, at least two rows, and all the columns.

Comment: I mean all possible combinations so that each combination is calculated once. The direction does not matter. Say, I have values a,b,c,d. I would then calculate a-b, a-c, a-d, b-d and c-d, and then the average of these. Or I could equally well calculate b-a, c-a, d-a, d-b and d-c and the average. The number of terms is always 9.

Comment: For some reason I am not able to attach a picture here.

Answer (score 2):

For 9 terms, the answer is simply (8 * B3 + 6 * C3 + 4 * D3 + 2 * E3 - 2 * G3 - 4 * H3 - 6 * I3 - 8 * J3) / 36, using only the forward direction (and yes, the direction does make a difference!).

Note that cell F3 isn't used at all, because it is cancelled out, the same as the "2" in your original example:  (1-2 + 1-3 + 2-3)/3 = (1 + 1-3 - 3)/3 = -4/3.

Comment: Nice algorithm!  In Excel 365, you can create a formula (for data in the same row): `=SUMPRODUCT(rng,SEQUENCE(,COUNT(rng),COUNT(rng)-1,-2))` and for the average difference divide by `COMBIN(COUNT(rng),2)` where `rng` refers to: `B3:J3` or some other contiguous range.

Answer (score 0):

Your need is for 9 terms and `Paul` has that answer.

Just to broaden that a smidge, to a general number of terms, for `n` values to use in your manner, you will have a polynomial of `n` terms the first of which (taking them left to right as you do) will have a coefficient equal to `n-1` and each succeeding term will see that coefficient lower by 2.

Hence `Paul`'s coefficients beginning with 8 and becoming 6, 4, 2, 0, -2, -4, -6, and -8.

So for 8 values, you'd have coefficients of: 7, 5, 3, 1, -2, -3, -5, and -7. So eight terms (a-h) like so:

```
7a + 5b + 3c + 1d - 1e - 3f - 5g - 7h
```

That gets their sum, considered "left to right." Or multiply the result by -1 to have their sum considered "right to left."

To find the average, you divide that by the `sum of the sequence from 1 to n-1`. In your case, that is 36. For the example just above for 8 values, it would be 28.

*(In the special case, presumably not yours as I imagine your example is simplified for us, of the values going from 1 to however many values there are (1 to 9 in your example's case), the result is simply `(1/3)*(n-1)`. NOT extensible to the general case real world numbers would bring!)*